# My account stopped working on the main site, but stll works here, please help!

Tags: support

Can someone help me with getting my accounts straightened out?

This account (which I'm posting with now) is my main account:  https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3068/randolf-richardson

This account is the new one I just created:  https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/5523/randolf-richardson

When I try to correct my eMail address from 5523 to what I had before in 3068, an error about an account already being registered appears.  I'm unable to login to the first account, and on other StackExchange web sites it has slowly been disappearing since a merge with some other user that shouldn't have happened went very badly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you like us to do?

Comment: @Sklivvz:  Thanks for asking -- I just wanted someone to look into this, and hopefully we can get these accounts merged once things are fixed up; Fabian has started on this process (see accepted answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can see is that your mail address for OpenID in the older account has a space where you now have a plus is the second account.

I'll let the SE developers handle this one. I could try to merge the accounts, but with the history your account has I'm not sure what would happen then.

Comment: Thanks!  Now I know exactly what happened -- at some point the OpenID system failed to encode a plus at the client side (an error that many developers seem to make in the client-side JavaScript code that runs on the browser).  If they can change that space to a plus sign then I will be able to login again with the first account.  I used "plussed addressing" to protect StackExchange messages from getting into spam detection folders, and also to track who shares my eMail addresses without my permission (StackExchange.com is one that has not shared my eMail addresses with anyone).

Comment: I had a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to login, and then I saw my eMail address with a + symbol in it (I guess someone fixed it?  If so, thanks for making this happen!) and then I was logged out.  So, I tried to login but OpenID is not recognizing my eMail address or just stuck in a loop, I can't tell which because it doesn't provide any useful feedback about what's happening (the login is a very confusing process).

Comment: @Randolf I don't know if it's fixed yet, it doesn't look like it to me. Maybe the easiest way is for you to just mail the team again, and provide the necessary detail.

Comment: I'll send them an eMail now with this question, and the other meta question I started a while back about this problem.  Thanks for taking your time so far to help me with this.